# Mocking classes with callback using Moq

Tags: callback, moq

I have a MockBuilder.cs file with the following code:

---

```
readonly IConnection _connection = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IConnection>();

...

        _connection.Stub(x => x.CreateModel()).WhenCalled(i =>
            {
                var channel = _channelPool.Pop();
                i.ReturnValue = channel;
                _channels.Add(channel);
                channel.Stub(x => x.CreateBasicProperties()).Return(_basicProperties);
                channel.Stub(x => x.IsOpen).Return(true);
                channel.Stub(x => x.BasicConsume(null, false, null, null))
                    .IgnoreArguments()
                    .WhenCalled(consumeInvokation =>
                    {
                        var consumerTag = (string)consumeInvokation.Arguments[2];
                        var consumer = (IBasicConsumer)consumeInvokation.Arguments[3];

                        consumer.HandleBasicConsumeOk(consumerTag);
                        _consumers.Add(consumer);
                    }).Return("");
            });
```

---

That works perfectly fine with Rhino Mocks, because ".WhenCalled" sets an interceptor on the CreateModel() method and when that is called, the lambda code above is ran and after it's done, the interceptor instructs the target to proceed.

I'm trying to to the same thing with Moq, but the Callback method is not really working for me ... or I'm doing it wrongly!!!

I've tried the following:

```
_connection.Setup(x => x.CreateModel()).Callback(() => { /* code in here */ });
```

but when CreateModel() is called, it does nothing ... I'd expect it to trigger the /* code in here */ bit.

It'd only work if I did the following:

```
_connection.Setup(x => x.CreateModel()).Callback(() => { /* code in here */ });
_connection.Object.CreateModel();
```

Thanks in advance for any help! It will definitely be very much appreciated :-)

Comment: That's how the `Callback` works, you need to invoke the method (in this case `CreateModel`) after you set it up.  Your last code snippet is exactly what I would do.  What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: Many thanks for your feedback Patrick. I've just realized that I was not using the exposed mock object by using ".Object". Regards